# compute sum dynamically with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to compute sum of subtotals dynamically but i always get this error:

```
document.getElementById("item_subtotal[" + cnt + "]") is null
```

My javascript code:

```
function calculateTotalAll(numitems) {     
  var cnt = 1;
  var totalAmt = 0;

  while(cnt <= numitems) {       
    totalAmt = parseInt(totalAmt) + parseInt(document.getElementById('item_subtotal[' + cnt + ']').value);
    cnt++;
  }

  document.getElementById('order_total').value = parseInt(totalAmt); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the html for the elements you are working with?

Comment: The last line doesn't need `parseInt()`; you need `string()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close but you need to check for fields with empty values instead of just assuming they contain numbers.  It works with only minor modifications in this [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bemace/EwxwA/2/)

Changed your function to this:

```
function calculateTotal(numitems) {
    var totalAmt = 0;

    for (var cnt = 1; cnt <= numitems; cnt++) {
        var subtotal = document.getElementById('item_subtotal[' + cnt + ']');
        if (subtotal.value === null || subtotal.value === '') {
            continue;
        }

        totalAmt += (subtotal.value * 1);
    }

    document.getElementById('order_total').innerHTML = totalAmt;
}
```

Comment: There's a problem with this line i guess: document.getElementById('item_subtotal[' + cnt + ']'); since it will prompt that  if (parseInt(subtot.value) == '') is null. HELP

Comment: But if I test it with document.getElementById('item_subtotal[1]') it works okay

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  It's easy enough to check for null if you need to, but since you should know how many elements there are it doesn't seem particularly necessary.

Comment: I ran the program and there's an error: if (parseInt(subtot.value) == '') is null

Answer (score 2):

I would look if the id exist, ie

```
  while(cnt <= numitems) {
    var curItem = document.getElementById('item_subtotal[' + cnt + ']');
    if(curItem!=null){
        totalAmt = parseInt(totalAmt) + parseInt(curItem.value);
    }
    cnt++;
  }
```

Furthermore, I would use the Firebug extension for Firefox to look at what might have gone wrong:

```
  while(cnt <= numitems) {
    var curItem = document.getElementById('item_subtotal[' + cnt + ']');
    if(curItem!=null){
        totalAmt = parseInt(totalAmt) + parseInt(curItem.value);
    }else{
        console.log('Couldn\'t find element item_subtotal[' + cnt + ']');
    }
    cnt++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The item hasn't been defined in your page - double check to make sure it's actually there in the source.

Comment: When I do example: alert(document.getElementById('item_subtotal[25]').value); will get the value

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be those square brackets.

From the [html4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

Comment: square brackets are fine, and also regularly used for the benefit of php scripts